# Mongoose.find() How to query document with property greater than some number OR value is null OR property doesnt exist?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, model, find

I have documents like let's say:

```
{
   "name": "John",
   "age" : 10
},
{
   "name": "Jack",
   "age" : 20
},
{
   "name": "Tom",
   "age" : 30
},
{
   "name": "Lisa"
}
```

How to construct query .find() to mongoose model querying about age eg.

- age greater than: 13
- age less than: 27

OR

- age property is null

OR

- age property doesn't exist?

Big thanks in advance for the response!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `$or` condition,

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    { age: { $gt: 13, $lt: 27 } },
    { age: null },
    { age: { $exists: false } }
  ]
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TdWKeg-KMVe)

Comment: Thanks for reply!

Reading mongo docs i would write this query exactly the some way BUT...
When i throw away from array {age: null} and {age: {$exists: false}} - only gt&lt obj left... it finds all the docs in range but when i add other two obj as above it finds ALL records.. wtf?

Comment: i am sure you missing something, you can check working playground.

Comment: Yes, its true, i made wrong check! Very GREAT HELP M8, THX! Works perfectly ;)